# Why isBuffer returns false for an fs.readFileSync call without encoding

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs, instanceof

In Node (`v6.3.1`) I am reading a file using `fs.readFileSync(path)`.

The result (`data`) is a buffer-like object that when I print to STDOUT (`console.log(data)`) I get:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[45,45,45,...]}
```

But calling

```
data instanceof Buffer
```

or

```
Buffer.isBuffer(data)
```

I always get `false`.

Why? How can I test if the returned data is a buffer?

Context: I simply want to avoid long dumps to STDOUT and clean up the output using `JSON.stringify(data, replacer)` by shortening the buffer outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when using a library ([node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa)) that tested the key data I was passing to it using Buffer.isBuffer().  This worked fine in the browser, but failed in a Node environment because isBuffer() returned false.

In my case, the reason was that Node's implementation of [Buffer.isBuffer()](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f52ccc828c26aee8fe78c82a8a23fabd21918b7/lib/buffer.js#L422) does a strict 'instanceof' check, and I was passing a [browserified Buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) object, which didn't pass the instanceof check.

Rather than trying to change node-rsa, I solved my problem by removing the direct dependency on the buffer library.

You could consider using the [is-buffer module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-buffer) in your code instead of Buffer.isBuffer().